# How to wait for MouseEvent User Input?

Tags: javafx

Im setting up a game, and the player needs to first click the model, and then its specified location, but its checking both at once and not awaiting user input. What should I do?

I've tried thread.sleep(); which doesn't seem to work except for just temporarily pausing the program then just doing the same thing.

```
@FXML
void MouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    if(event.getSource() == b11) {
                if(event.getSource() == c1) {
                    b11.setTranslateY(-100);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("C1 not clicked");
                    }
                }
}
```

I would like it to pause after the first if(event.getSource()), but it just moves on to the next line without waiting for user input.

Comment: The controller needs to keep track which stage of clicks the user is at, and have the event handler do different thing based on the different stages. Your sequence consists of 2 clicks, so there should be at least 2 stages that your controller needs to keep track of (on top of the "none" stage).

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.